# How can I write a method in which if a user sign up that user get a 4 digit id? And that id increases whenever new user signup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, server

How can I make a method in which if a user sign up that user get a 4 digit id? And that id increases whenever new user signup?

In NodeJS that id should be random but it should be at least 4 digit and it move on & on whenever a new user sign up but the minimum value should be 4 digit only so how can I built that method? if its a large process than please explain me I will get a idea or if its easy and it can be done in less lines of code than please provide snippets of that example you can check my code

user.controller:

```
const user_module = require('./user.modules');


class user_controller extends user_module {

    static create_user = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.save_user_details(req)
            let message = 'Success';
            res.send({
                sucess: true,
                message: message,
                data: response
            })
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status.code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = err.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message: message
            })
        }
    }

    static get_users = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.retrieve_user(req)
            let message = 'Success';
            res.send({
                sucess: true,
                message: message,
                data: response
            })
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status.code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = err.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message: message
            })
        }
    }

    static otp_verify = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.verify_user(req)
            if(response.status){
                res.send({
                    success: true,
                    message: response.message,
                    data: response.user
                })
            }else{
                res.status(400).send({
                    success: false,
                    error: false,
                    message: response.message
                })
            }
          
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status_code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = error.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message:message
            })
            res.end();
        }

    }

    
}

module.exports = user_controller
```

user.modules:

```
const models = require('../models');

class user_module {

    static save_user_details = async (req) => {
        try {
            console.log("req body", req.body)
            const { profileImage } = req.body
            let set_data = req.body
            if (!!profileImage) {
                set_data.profileImage = profileImage
            }
            return await models.users.create(set_data)

        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    static retrieve_user = async (req) => {
        try {
            let {limit, pagination} = req.query

            let query = {}
            let projection ={__v: 0}
            let options = {
                lean: true,
                sort: {_id: -1},
                skip: !Number(pagination) ? 0: Number(pagination) * !Number(limit) ? 10: Number(limit),
                limit: !Number(limit) ? 10: Number(limit)
            }
            let users = await models.users.find(query, projection, options)
            let count = await models.users.count(query)
            return {users, count}
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    static verify_user = async (req) => {
        try {
            console.log("req body", req.body)
            const { otp, user_id } = req.body
            if(otp == '123456'){
                let user = await models.users.findById(user_id)
                return {user: user, status: true, message: 'success'}
            }else{
                return {user: null, status: false, message: 'Otp Invalid'}
            }

        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

}

module.exports = user_module
```

Schema:

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const Users = new Schema({
        name: String, 
        phoneNumber: String,
        userid: String,
        profileImage: {
            type: String,
            default: 'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/146-1468479_my-profile-icon-blank-profile-picture-circle-hd.png'
        },
        about: String,
        selectedCountry: {
            type: Object
        }
    })
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("users", Users)
```

Comment: If you generated a random 4 and increment you are eventually going to run out of numbers especially if you use a randomization function that might give you 9999. Why increment?

Comment: How are you storing things?

Comment: @DanielA.White i am storing user data in mongodb

Comment: @cyberwombat yes i know that will be the problem and i do have a solution for it "Any way to do that? or any way to atleast  increment the value of the id when new user joins but the minimum val should be 4 digit and it should be also  unique

Comment: Not that your requirement makes much sense. but `let newid = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999- currentId)) + currentId + 1)` will generate a random number with `currentId < newid < 10000`

Comment: @derpirscher answer it on the question also check my Schema there i have given userid: String, check it and aswer there

Comment: Your question says "*four digit id*" and "*increase*" Both strongly indicate you are dealing with numerical ids. You can always do `.toString()` afterwards to convert to string.

Comment: @derpirscher answer it on the question